# Android Saving checkbox preferences

Tags: android, checkbox, sharedpreferences

i'm going crazy to save the state of a group of checkbox in my project.
Imagine a set of 8 checkbox that the user have to check or not to remember something like a collection.
This is what i have accomplished... but is barely usabe. I pasted all the code of the class.
Sorry if i didn't use well the code block.. i really do not understand how..
Thank you.

`package com.example.eurocollection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Francia extends Activity {
    // Identificatore delle preferenze dell'applicazione
    private final static String MY_PREFERENCES = "MyPref";
    // Costante relativa al nome della particolare preferenza
    private final static String TEXT_DATA_KEY = "textData";

   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_francia);
        updatePreferencesData();//carica le preferenze
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_francia, menu);
        return true;
    }


   @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    //come salvare le preferenze
    public void savePreferencesData(View view) {
        // Otteniamo il riferimento alle Preferences
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // Otteniamo il corrispondente Editor
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        // Modifichiamo il valore con quello inserito nell'EditText
        //EditText outputView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputData);
        CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2efrance99);

        cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked){
                    editor.putBoolean("MY_PREFERENCES", cb1.isChecked());

               cb1.setChecked(settings.getBoolean("MY_PREFERENCES",true));

               }

            }
            });
 updatePreferencesData();
} 
// fine copiato
private void updatePreferencesData(){
// Leggiamo le Preferences
  SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
// Leggiamo l'informazione associata alla proprietà TEXT_DATA
  Boolean textData = prefs.getBoolean(TEXT_DATA_KEY, false);
// Lo impostiamo alla TextView
  CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2cfrance99);
  cb1.setChecked(textData);
}


}`

Comment: I don't see `commit()` called on the preference Editor anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

so where do you call `savePreferencesData()` method?
and where's the editor.commit()?

Comment: well that's because i didn't understand how to use them properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `editor.commit()`, so that any changes you've made actually happen.

Do this after your `putBoolean`, and it should work.